# Is there a GNOME application with a GUI for verifying PGP signatures?

Tags: software-recommendation, pgp

Is there a GNOME application with a GUI that enables one to verify a PGP signature, something equivalent to Kleopatra for KDE?

Comment: Have you tried the _seahorse-nautilus_ extension? It gives Nautilus a context menu to sign, crypt or decrypt files.

Answer (score 1):

[GnuPG Shell](http://www.tech-faq.com/gnupg-shell.html) should do it

Comment: Not in Ubuntu repositories :-(